# Make the logo and links on the same line in header

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm making a website and in the header I need a logo and a horizontal set of links.  The logo must be on the left and the links must be on the right.  The problem I'm running into is that if I add too many links to the list, it will wrap to the next line, but I need it to be closely attached to the right side of the page.  Both the banner and the list of links are in the header.  My CSS is as follows.

```
header{
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
    background-color:#AC222A;
    color:white;
}

links{
    position: relative;
    height: 10;
    width: 10%;
    float: right;
    top: 35%;
    display: inline;
}

banner{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1%
    left: 1%;
    height; 10;
    width: 15%
    float: left;
}
```

And the HTML is as follows:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<div id="header">
    <div id = "banner">
        <img src="pictures/logo_logo.png">
    </div>
    <div id = "links">
        <a href="">home</a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="About.html">About</a>    
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
</div>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem was the width.  After taking this attribute out, the problem fixed itself.  Thanks @sdcr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's missing the `#` on the id names in the CSS. In fact the whole layout can be done with a simple `float`, so move links before banner in the HTML.

```css
#header {
    background-color:#AC222A;
    color:white;
}
#links {
    float:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <div id="links">
        <a href="">home</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="About.html">About</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; <a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
    <div id="banner">
        <img src="pictures/logo_logo.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** (transferring the comments into this) - to fix the problem based on your existing code, you have `#links{width:10%;}` set there, just remove that.

Comment: I omitted the # because the formatting would break it it would look totally messed up. The CSS mostly works, it the links just refuse to stay on the same line without breaking down to the next.

Comment: @Csteele5 you have this `width: 10%;` set on the link, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

After taking out the Width attribute, the link menu shows up nicely formatted with no problems.

Comment: Glad to hear that, well, did my answer or comments help?

Comment: Yup, thanks to you my site is functioning as intended :)

Comment: Thanks, by the way `height: 10;` is not valid.

Comment: Oops!  Thanks for catching that :P

Comment: Also, all your <div id="header"> stuff should be stay inside <body>.